# Private chain: Run out of gas even with a high balance

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

#### Context

- geth: Geth/v1.4.18-stable/linux/go1.5.1
- solc: 0.4.6

I am writing a contract testing it on a private network with a large amount of pre-allocated gas.
The following works perfectly fine:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract accountList {

    address[] allowedClient;

    function add(address client) returns (bool) {
        allowedClient.push(client);
        return true;
    }

    function get() constant returns (address[]) {
        return allowedClient;
    }

}
```

Addresses are well added when I call the add method. I can retrieve them calling the get method.
This cost me nothing since I use the same account to call the contract and to mine the transaction (I earn more gas mining the transaction than I use to call the contract).

#### Issue

I run out of gas when I add a second array with the same behaviour:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract accountList {

    address[] allowedClient;        
    address[] test;

    function add(address client) returns (bool) {
        allowedClient.push(client);
        test.push(client);
        return true;
    }

    function get() constant returns (address[]) {
        return allowedClient;
    }

}
```

Calling the add method make me run out of gas

```
 contractInstance.add(coinbase, {from: coinbase}, function(error, result) {
    ...
 }
```

Debug in the geth console:

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
1.245e+21
> var t = web3.debug.traceTransaction('0x456...')
> t.structLogs[t.structLogs.length-1].error
"Out of gas"
```

A balance of 1.245e+21 should be enough isn't it?
Which configuration can I use to avoid gas limitation on my private network?

Comment: How did you call the `add` method? Can you show that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the gas will be set to 90,000 when executing a transaction to a smart contract, and 21,000 when execution a transaction to transfer ethers to another account.

Here's a screenshot showing that you will need more than the default 90,000 gas and at least 103,866
[image]

You will need to manually specify what your gas limits are, e.g.:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: ..., to: ..., gas: 150000})
```

And for comparison, if you omit the `test.push(...)` statement, the gas cost for executing `add(...)` is 63,383 and the gas in this situation is much smaller than the 90,000 default gas limit:

[image]